# Как в pug-миксин вставить аргумент в значение атрибута?

Tags: pug

Вот миксин который не компилируется. Требуется просто вставить src картинки в style.

```
mixin team(img_src)
```

span.team-card__photo(style="background-image: url("=#{img_src}");")

Пробовал и без скобок и без решёточки - бесполезно... Как это правильно делается?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сделать так:

```js
mixin team(img_src)
  span.team-card__photo(style="background-image: url(" + (img_src) +")")
  
+team('img/picture.jpg')
```